# Nested indentation of text blocks

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How can I doubly indent some lines of text?

The general idea is...

```
Normal
Once indented
Once indented
Twice indented 
Once indented
...
```

The following is my attempt but it only indents once.

```
  for each $v \in win$\\

\addtolength{\leftskip}{1cm}
if ($pl(v) = 1 \& \exists (v,v') \in E : v' \in win$)\\
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1cm}$win \cup= v; st \cup = \{v \rightarrow v'\}$}\\
if ($pl(v) = 2 \& \forall (v,v') \in E : v' \in win$)\\
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1cm}$wim \cup= v;$}\\
if ($pl(v) = 2 \& \exists (v,v') \in E : v' \in lose$)\\
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1cm}$lose \cup=v$;}\\
```

Could someone please tell me a better way of doing this, and/or why my attempt doesn't work?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
\hskip\parindent\=\hskip\parindent\=\kill
For each $v\in win$,\+\\
if ($pl(v)=1\ \&\ \exists(v,v')\in E:v'\in win$)\\
\>$\mathit{win}\cup=v;st\cup=\{v\rightarrow v'\}$\\
if ($pl(v) = 2 \& \forall (v,v') \in E : v' \in win$)\\
\>$wim \cup= v;$\\
if ($pl(v) = 2 \& \exists (v,v') \in E : v' \in lose$)\\
\>$lose \cup=v$;\\
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

In the interest of keeping the answer as close to your example as possible, I've kept the math exactly as you wrote it, but I don't think that's a good idea. Writing things like `$win$` will typeset it as the multiplication of *w*, *i*, and *n*.

As an explanation,

- `\=` sets the tab stops. So here, I'm setting 2 tab stops: one at 1 `\parindent` and one 1 `\parindent` later.
- `\kill` ignores the previous text which is used just for setting the tab stops.
- `\+` indents all following commands by one tab stop.
- `\>` moves to the next tab stop.

There are analogous `\-` and `\<` commands that do what you would expect. (There are also `\'` and `` \` `` which do strange things inside the tabbing environment, but I've never used them.)

Answer (score 3):

I nest `quote` environments when I want to achieve such an effect:

```
Normal
  \begin{quote}
  Once indented
  Once indented
    \begin{quote}
    Twice indented 
    \end{quote}
  Once indented
  \end{quote}
```

You may also wish to define your own indentation environment where you can control left and right margins and vertical skips before and after. But that's a different question.

For example, you can define an environment `indentmore` this way (initially, I've borrowed `changemargin` from [this page](http://help-csli.stanford.edu/tex/latex-margins.shtml), thanks to *Hendrik* for converting it to LaTeX):

```
\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1
\parsep=0pt\topsep=0pt\partopsep=0pt}
\item[]}
{\endlist}

\newenvironment{indentmore}{\begin{changemargin}{1cm}{0cm}}{\end{changemargin}}
```

Change `\parsep`, `\partopsep` and `\topsep` to control vertical spacing).

This is how nested `indentmore` look like in text:

[image: nested indentmore environments]

You can find the complete source of the example [at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/8B9QcvqR).

Comment: With `quote` you will get increased left _and_ right margins. Moreover, it will give additional vertical space.

Comment: @jetxee: This way of controlling the vertical skip with `\vspace` is definitely not recommendable.

Comment: Updated the solution with use of `\topsep` and `\parsep`.

Comment: @jetxee: Setting `\topsep` and `\parsep` is a lot better; you also have to set `\partopsep=0pt`. However, it's not a good idea to promote the usage of `\def` and `\let` here; they don't check if a control sequence has been defined before.

Comment: @jetxee: I've edited your answer to show what I meant in my previous comment. Hope you don't mind. I've marked my edits in a way that it's clear that I messed around there. You may want to further edit your question and remove the things I wrote in slanted letters. You could use my code as a replacement of your `\def\changemargin...`.

Comment: Thank you, Hendrik. It was very kind of you to complete the answer. I've replaced the code with your definition.

Comment: @jetxee: No problem. Just in case you don't know: If you had used "@Hendrik" in your comments, then I would have been notified of your comments. This way I just checked back from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you want to achieve. *Indentation* usually means that only the first line of a paragraph is indented (by the `\parindent` amount). You increased `\leftskip`, which means that the whole paragraph gets an increased left margin.

Your attempt with `\leftskip` didn't work because you need to end the paragraph before ending the group with `}`. The following works:

```
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{1cm}This has an increased left margin.\par}
```

If you only want to indent the first line of a paragraph (or if you only have single lines anyway), then you can use

```
{\addtolength{\parindent}{1cm}This has an additional indentation of 1cm.}
```

(No need to end the paragraph here.)

Comment: I always thought that *indentation* means the blank space between a margin and the beginning of an indented line, and by margin meaning either left or right margin!

Comment: @Yiannis: It's possible that my usage of "margin" is not correct. But it is also used in the explanation of `\leftskip` in the TeXbook, p. 100.

Comment: It's also possible that my interpretation is also wrong!

Answer (score 1):

The given text looks like an equation which could be aligned, hence `\eqalign` might be appropriate here (this is in plain-tex):

```
$$\eqalign{
{\rm for each\ } v \in win\cr
{\rm if\ } \big(pl(v) &= 1 \mathrel{\&} \exists (v,v') \in E : v' \in win\big)\cr
win \cup&= v; st \cup = \{v \to v'\}\cr
{\rm if\ } \big(pl(v) &= 2 \mathrel{\&} \forall (v,v') \in E : v' \in win\big)\cr
wim \cup&= v;\cr
{\rm if\ } \big(pl(v) &= 2 \mathrel{\&} \exists (v,v') \in E : v' \in lose\big)\cr
lose \cup&=v;\cr
}$$
\bye
```

Which yields:

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 0):

```
\hspace{1cm} One indent \linebreak
\hspace{2cm} Two indent \linebreak
```

or

```
\indent One indent \linebreak
\indent \indent Two indent \linebreak
```

Though the latter is a bit sloppy.

Comment: Neither of these seem to work. The first only indents the first line, with the second is unaffected. The latter does nothing at all.

Comment: @asdf123, @Mica: At the beginning of a line you have to use `\hspace*` instead of `\hspace` to really get the space.

Answer (score 0):

The best solutions are normally the simpler. TeX defines a macro called `narrower` that simply makes a paragraph indent by one more `parindent`. Similarly we can define a macro called `wider` as shown in the minimal example below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\parindent=1em
\lipsum[1]
\narrower
\lipsum[2]
\narrower\narrower
\lipsum[1]
\def\wider{%
 \advance\leftskip -\parindent
 \advance\rightskip -\parindent}
\wider\lipsum[1]
\wider\lipsum[1]
\wider\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Should you not want the right side indentation you can remove the `rightskip` in both the definition of `wider` as well as `narrower`. A gentle reminder, is always best to elaborate your code with a full working minimal example.